# How to generate multiple cucumber json file while running same feature file for multiple users?

Tags: json, testng, report, cucumber-jvm

**@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/xxxxxx/xxxxx.feature", tags = "@tag1", glue = {
        "com.xxxx.sfdc.opportunities.stepdefinitions" }, format = { "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json" })**

The above is my cucumber options which is using testng as runner by extending AbstractTestNGCucumberTests. I am calling this feature file via testng xml which runs the same feature file for 4 different users.

**So the cucumber report json file is overridden for every run. How can I avoid this and get the report for every run (for every single user)**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [test-ng extension qaf](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) which provides [gherkin client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) for gherkin users. In addition it also has it's own bdd implementation with additional features.